# If questions with Devise and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, devise, cancan

I want only the people who created an object e.g. a registry to see something =, but struggling to define everything with Devise

Here is the code:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && ***"current_user = registry the user created?"?(struggling with the second part)*** %>
```

Thanks in advance

P.S. I'm using cancan, but this will not help in my show page where I want to show page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of devise but of cancan.

You need to define the ability inside your cancan ability file:

```
user ||= User.new
can :read, Registry, :user_id => user.id
```

This way cancan's authorize method will allow you to do stuff like this:

```
@registry = Registry.find(params[:id])
authorize! :read, @registry
```

Obviously authorize! will throw an error if the user has no access to this resource.

If you simply want to check this in the view the registry you use:

```
<% if can? :read, @registry %>
  do your thing here
<% end %>
```

By the way, all of this is documented on the cancan frontpage: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan